# Get selected nodes from treeview UWP

Tags: checkbox, uwp, treeview

I am developing UWP app, and I am struggling with treeview checkboxes.
I need to know which nodes have checkboxes checked.

I have tried using

```
mytreeview.SelectedNodes
```

but it always returns null. This is my [treeview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802906/uwp-scale-textblock-inside-treeview-text-wrapping) 
I have also tried using

```
<TreeViewItem IsSelected="{x:Bind IsSelected ,Mode=TwoWay}" ...>
```

and in page.cs

```
public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
```

but when I check the checkbox it is still false

Answer (score 0):

> Get selected nodes from treeview UWP

Please check this case [replay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56786192/7254781),  `TreeViewItem` contains `IsSelected` property, we could create model class with `IsSelected` property and bind it. After item selected IsSelected value will be changed, so you could **foreach** the itemsource then get the selected item.

```
public class ExplorerItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public enum ExplorerItemType { Folder, File };
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public ExplorerItemType Type { get; set; }
    private ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem> m_children;
    public ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem> Children
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_children == null)
            {
                m_children = new ObservableCollection<ExplorerItem>();
            }
            return m_children;
        }
        set
        {
            m_children = value;
        }
    }

    private bool m_isExpanded;
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return m_isExpanded; }
        set
        {
            if (m_isExpanded != value)
            {
                m_isExpanded = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsExpanded");
            }
        }
    }

    private bool m_isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return m_isSelected; }

        set
        {
            if (m_isSelected != value)
            {
                m_isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }

    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added it to my Item Class [link](https://imgur.com/a/mtr4ozc) and added INotifyPropertyChanged interface to that class. But when I check that checkbox from my application it doesnt change IsSelected property. [link](https://imgur.com/a/8GJ6z6G) This in my xaml I have `<TreeViewItem IsSelected="{x:Bind IsSelected ,Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: As I said, I have tested your code sample. This is my [class](https://imgur.com/a/edtxqCA) But the IsSelected property is still false. And in my Xaml Treeview, I have `IsSelected="{x:Bind IsSelected ,Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: I test the code sample again, if I select the item `IsSelected` set method will be invoked, could share your sample with us, I will test base on your sample.